# AngularJS $scope do not push information and give them to the view's ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have made a small AngularJS app. Very simple.

Everything is working fine. In my view, I have two inputs whose value I want to pass to the ng-repeat.

Here is my controller:

```
LoginApp.controller("RegisterController", function($scope){
        $scope.registerForm = [{
            name : "Something",
            work : 'SomeWork',
        }];

        $scope.RegisterSubmit = function($scope){
            $scope.registerForm.push({
                name : $scope.register.username,
                work : $scope.register.password,
            });
        };
    });
```

In here the default data passed to the `registerForm` is just rendered finely in the page, but when it comes to the dynamically inserted data via input and hitting button, noting happens no error is alos outputted in the console. Here is my view:

```
<form  >
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div ng-repeat="each in registerForm">
                            {{ each.name }}
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Username</label>
                                    <input name="username" ng-model="register.username"
                                           class="form-control"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Password</label>
                                    <input name="password" type="password"
                                         ng-model="register.password" class="form-control"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label >Password Confirm</label>
                                    <input name="password" type="password"
                                           class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <input ng-submit="RegisterSubmit()"  type="submit" name="user-register"
                                       class="btn btn-info btn-lg" value="Register"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

It's worth mentioning that Controller is passed correctly to the DOM element since the default JSON data are just shown, also my body is bootstrapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Dalorzo said was the first thing I noticed too. But the fiddle I made still didn't work.
I tried with a regular button. Perhaps the problems is something else about ngSubmit that I'm forgetting.

And perhaps this fiddle can inspire you: http://jsfiddle.net/Fa6rA/3/

```
<!-- trying with a regular button -->
<button
    class="btn btn-info btn-lg"
    data-ng-click="RegisterSubmit()"
    type="button" name="user-register"
    >
    Register as Button
</button>
```

**UPDATE**

@Dalorzo nailed it. Here's the fiddle for sake of completeness:
http://jsfiddle.net/Fa6rA/4/

Comment: ngSubmit is form directive and not a button directive

Comment: @Dalorzo Yes! That's it! I knew it was something simple. =)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `$scope` parameter from your function:

```
$scope.RegisterSubmit = function($scope /* here*/){
            $scope.registerForm.push({
                name : $scope.register.username,
                work : $scope.register.password,
            });
        };
```

It should be like this instead:

```
 $scope.RegisterSubmit = function(){
                $scope.registerForm.push({
                    name : $scope.register.username,
                    work : $scope.register.password,
                });
            };
```

Since you are calling the function without parameter: `ng-submit="RegisterSubmit()"` within your function it should be `undefined`.

Check your console there you should see something like: 
`Cannot read property 'registerForm' of undefined`

Additionally `ngSubmit` is form directive and not a button directive:

```
<form
  ng-submit="">
...
</form>
```

Instead of this:

```
<input ng-submit="RegisterSubmit()"...
```

Try this

```
<form ng-submit="RegisterSubmit()"...
```

Or

```
 <input ng-click="RegisterSubmit()"...
```